# Unity-iOS: Native iOS code development in Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity. I have done a character walk animation in 3ds max and imported in Unity. I created Xcode project for iOS through Unity, and animation works as expected.
I want to develop some UI button controls on screen and animate this animation in my iOS app, only when this button is clicked. How do i code it now for this UI controls and events? Do i need do adding these controls and events on the Xcode project (which created by Unity) (or) I can do everything like this kind of native code in Unity itself?

Please advise!

Thank you!

Getsy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all UI in the Unity itself. You have these options:

- [Old Unity GUI system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GUI.html). It is pretty easy to program, but it is awful in terms of performance and usability for designers — it's created completely from code, with no editors. It's almost never used in commercial products except for debugging and developer tools. However, it's still a good option for prototypes.
- Use other GUI package. There are a lot of 2d and UI packages for Unity of all kinds. Currently the most popular one is NGUI, which is pad, but also has an evalution version.
- Create your own UI framework (still in Unity). Just wanted to mention that this is a viable option, but it's obviously the worst one for your case.
- Wait for the new 2D/GUI Unity framework. It's supposed to come out in 4.3 version, and it is just around the corner; more than that, the original NGUI author is working on it.

In you place, I'd create basic prototype controls with built-in Unity3d GUI, and by the time I'd need to create something more presentable, new Unity GUI would hopefully already be there.

Comment: May i please know, from which Unity version they have started supporting for iOS programming?